# Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.4.5Java(0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

i'm Creating a  Spring Boot Project and Configuring Dependencies , but it's giving me 4   errors

PS : i'm using spring boot 2.4.3
and

-> Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.4.5Java(0)

AND

-> Missing artifact  org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.4

AND

->Failure to transfer org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.4.5 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

END

->Failure to transfer  f org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.4 from  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TEST_WEB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TEST_WEB</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
     <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>


   

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
        <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        
    </build>


</project>

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TEST_WEB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TEST_WEB</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
     <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>txw2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>


   

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
        <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: How did you create the project? And please show the pom.xml

Comment: This sounds like network or firewall issues.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i create it here : https://start.spring.io/  then i took the  downloaded package and i  opened  it in Visual studio

Comment: You retry to build the project via `mvn clean verify -U` (there had been an network issue in between)...

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLOTION :  I  Forget to Set  the JAVA_HOME Variable in Windows

Comment: 2.4.5 @EntityScan was not working for me